# Two electrical sources for one load

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, power-engineering, ats

How can two electrical sources 220 volts feed one electrical load about 20 amperes where the first  power source spends all its capacity and when required the remainder is taken from the second source?

Comment: What are those 220VAC sources? 2 independent generators? Or a generator and a mains AC outlet? Or 2 separate mains AC outlets in the same room or house where using only one outlet blows the breaker or makes the outlet smoking hot? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

This is a power grid (or microgrid) function. It requires the two source voltages to be matched and also the frequency and phase if they are AC sources. Once matched, the sources can be paralleled. Each source must have a current control or generator excitation control system that limits the amount of power that is dispatched. There must be a supervisory control system and likely a human interface system that decides how much power to dispatch from each source under specified circumstances. Appropriate measures must be taken to protect the sources and to maintain system stability. That is a general outline of the system required. Evaluating the alternative design approaches and implementing a design is too broad a subject to be covered here.